# Sound Manager Classes for Windows

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, winapi

I need some classes for playing short wav sounds, this classes would load this wav files into memory when an instance created, play sounds in background when needed, release this wav files from memory when an instance disposed.

How can I do this on C# for windows (.Net 2.0)? (Win API's sndPlaySound, OpenAL or may be any wrapper)
Ideally I would love to find an exist solution that simple and able to solve my task.

Do you know any solutions for this issue?

Comment: please don't duplicate tags in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the System.Media.SoundPlayer class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

System.Media.SystemSounds too.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.aspx